# converting images to indexed 2-bit grayscale BMP

Tags: imagemagick, bmp, grayscale

First of all, my question is different to [How do I convert image to 2-bit per pixel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155092/how-do-i-convert-image-to-2-bit-per-pixel) and unfortunately its solution does not work in my case...

I need to convert images to 2-bit per pixel grayscale BMP format. The sample image has the following properties:

```
Color Model: RGB
Depth: 4
Is Indexed: 1
Dimension: 800x600
Size: 240,070 bytes (4 bits per pixel but only last 2 bits are used to identify the gray scales as 0/1/2/3 in decimal or 0000/0001/0010/0011 in binary, plus 70 bytes BMP metadata or whatever)
```

[image: sample]

The Hex values of the beginning part of the sample BMP image:
[image: head of sample image]

The 3s represent white pixels at the beginning of the image. Further down there are some 0s, 1s and 2s representing black, dark gray and light gray:
[image: mid-part of sample image]

With the command below,

```
convert pic.png -colorspace gray +matte -depth 2 out.bmp
```

I can get *visually* correct 4-level grayscale image, but wrong depth or size per pixel:

```
Color Model: RGB
Depth: 8 (expect 4)
Dimension: 800x504
Size: 1,209,738 bytes (something like 3 bytes per pixel, plus metadata)
(no mention of indexed colour space)
```

[image: conversion outcome]

Please help...

Comment: What awful program requires you to use 2 bpp? ImageMagick does not support that. NetPBM does not support that. Wikipedia says *"Typical values are 1, 4, 8, 16, 24 and 32"* here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: it's for e-paper display module that natively supports 4 level gray scale display. its manufacture only provides an image converter for Windows platform, but I'm a Linux/Mac user.

Comment: Maybe try running their program in VirtualBox - which is free and will allow you to run Windows on your Mac and Linux boxes. Or try `wine`. Can you provide a product name & link to the module manufacturer and, if it rains or I get bored, I might write a Mac/Linux version. No promises though.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to *pollute* your lovely Mac with 'Windows trash', you could run up a free Amazon E2C Windows box and install their converter on there:-)

Comment: By the way, you can make ImageMagick create a palettised/indexed BMP by adding `-type palette` to your command.

Comment: hi Mark, thanks for your comments. I do have Windows in a VM for certain applications, but I'm a big scripting+automation fan, and I prefer non-GUI for efficiency :-) The Windows BMP converter is 7zipped as UC-GUI-BitmapConvert.7z at http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/4.3inch_e-Paper_Software It's a single executable, which opens an existing BMP, choose convert->2bpp and saves as the desired format for the e-paper module. I've written a Python library to update the e-paper via cmdline instead of its GUI utility. Once I get over this hurdle, it'll be all-cmdline.

Comment: just tried `-type palette`, didn't work. still getting 3bytes per pixel.

Comment: I think I'm going to manually build the 2bpp BMP files by bytes. once I create a BMP file header following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header , mapping the rest pixels to binary is easy.

Comment: Cool, good luck! Remember to share it back as an answer that you can then accept. Consider letting ImageMagick do the depth reduction, greyscale conversion, alpha removal, and conversion to 8-bit so that your program can be very simple... `convert input.png +matte -colors 4 -depth 8 -colorspace gray pgm:- | yourProgram > 2bpp.bmp`. Or, equally but with the lighter weight NetPBM `pngtopam input.png | pamcolors 4 ... | yourProgram`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2654860/2836621 ... may provide a starting point.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the inspiration! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I have written a Python script following Mark's hints (see comments under original question) to manually create a 4-level gray scale BMP with 4bpp. This specific BMP format construction is for the 4.3 inch e-paper display module made by WaveShare. Specs can be found here: http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/4.3inch_e-Paper

Here's how to pipe the original image to my code and save the outcome.

```
convert in.png -colorspace gray +matte -colors 4 -depth 2 -resize '800x600>' pgm:- | ./4_level_gray_4bpp_BMP_converter.py > out.bmp
```

Contents of `4_level_gray_4bpp_BMP_converter.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""

### Sample BMP header structure, total = 70 bytes
### !!! little-endian !!!

Bitmap file header 14 bytes
42 4D          "BM"
C6 A9 03 00    FileSize = 240,070       <= dynamic value
00 00          Reserved
00 00          Reserved
46 00 00 00    Offset = 70 = 14+56

DIB header (bitmap information header)
BITMAPV3INFOHEADER 56 bytes
28 00 00 00    Size = 40
20 03 00 00    Width = 800              <= dynamic value
58 02 00 00    Height = 600             <= dynamic value
01 00          Planes = 1
04 00          BitCount = 4
00 00 00 00    compression
00 00 00 00    SizeImage
00 00 00 00    XPerlPerMeter
00 00 00 00    YPerlPerMeter
04 00 00 00    Colours used = 4
00 00 00 00    ColorImportant
00 00 00 00    Colour definition index 0
55 55 55 00    Colour definition index 1
AA AA AA 00    Colour definition index 2
FF FF FF 00    Colour definition index 3

"""

# to insert File Size, Width and Height with hex strings in order
BMP_HEADER = "42 4D %s 00 00 00 00 46 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 %s %s 01 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 55 55 00 AA AA AA 00 FF FF FF 00"
BMP_HEADER_SIZE = 70
BPP = 4
BYTE = 8
ALIGNMENT = 4 # bytes per row

import sys
from re import findall

DIMENTIONS = 1
PIXELS = 3

BLACK     = "0"
DARK_GRAY = "1"
GRAY      = "2"
WHITE     = "3"

# sample data:
# ['P5\n', '610 590\n', '255\n', '<1 byte per pixel for 4 levels of gray>']
# where item 1 is always P5, item 2 is width heigh, item 3 is always 255, items 4 is pixels/colours
data = sys.stdin.readlines()

width = int(data[DIMENTIONS].strip().split(' ')[0])
height = int(data[DIMENTIONS].strip().split(' ')[1])


if not width*height == len(data[PIXELS]):
    print "Error: pixel data (%s bytes) and image size (%dx%d pixels) do not match" % (len(data[PIXELS]),width,height)
    sys.exit()

colours = [] # enumerate 4 gray levels
for p in data[PIXELS]:
    if not p in colours:
        colours.append(p)
        if len(colours) == 4:
            break

# it's possible for the converted pixels to have less than 4 gray levels

colours = sorted(colours) # sort from low to high

# map each colour to e-paper gray indexes
# creates hex string of pixels
# e.g. "0033322222110200....", which is 4 level gray with 4bpp

if len(colours) == 1: # unlikely, but let's have this case here
    pixels = data[PIXELS].replace(colours[0],BLACK)
elif len(colours) == 2: # black & white
    pixels = data[PIXELS].replace(colours[0],BLACK)\
                         .replace(colours[1],WHITE)
elif len(colours) == 3:
    pixels = data[PIXELS].replace(colours[0],DARK_GRAY)\
                         .replace(colours[1],GRAY)\
                         .replace(colours[2],WHITE)
else: # 4 grays as expected
    pixels = data[PIXELS].replace(colours[0],BLACK)\
                         .replace(colours[1],DARK_GRAY)\
                         .replace(colours[2],GRAY)\
                         .replace(colours[3],WHITE)

# BMP pixel array starts from last row to first row
# and must be aligned to 4 bytes or 8 pixels
padding = "F" * ((BYTE/BPP) * ALIGNMENT - width % ((BYTE/BPP) * ALIGNMENT))
aligned_pixels = ''.join([pixels[i:i+width]+padding for i in range(0, len(pixels), width)][::-1])

# convert hex string to represented byte values
def Hex2Bytes(hexStr):
    hexStr = ''.join(hexStr.split(" "))
    bytes = []
    for i in range(0, len(hexStr), 2):
        byte = int(hexStr[i:i+2],16)
        bytes.append(chr(byte))
    return ''.join(bytes)

# convert integer to 4-byte little endian hex string
# e.g. 800 => 0x320 => 00000320 (big-endian) =>20030000 (little-endian)
def i2LeHexStr(i):
    be_hex = ('0000000'+hex(i)[2:])[-8:]
    n = 2 # split every 2 letters
    return ''.join([be_hex[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(be_hex), n)][::-1])

BMP_HEADER = BMP_HEADER % (i2LeHexStr(len(aligned_pixels)/(BYTE/BPP)+BMP_HEADER_SIZE),i2LeHexStr(width),i2LeHexStr(height))

sys.stdout.write(Hex2Bytes(BMP_HEADER+aligned_pixels))
```

Edit: everything about this e-paper display and my code to display things on it can be found here: https://github.com/yy502/ePaperDisplay

[image]

Comment: Well done! And thanks for sharing back with the community. Maybe add a few words with the make & model of the device so that other users find your answer when searching. Well done again!

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Imagemagick 6.9.10.23 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra

Input:
[image]

```
convert logo.png -colorspace gray -depth 2 -type truecolor logo_depth8_gray_rgb.bmp
```

[image]

Adding -type truecolor converts the image to RGB, but in gray tones as per the -colorspace gray. And the depth 2 creates only 4 colors in the histogram.

```
identify -verbose logo_depth8_gray_rgb.bmp
```

```
Image:
  Filename: logo_depth8_gray_rgb.bmp
  Format: BMP (Microsoft Windows bitmap image)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 640x480+0+0
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: Grayscale
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianness: Undefined
  Depth: 8/2-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 2-bit
    green: 2-bit
    blue: 2-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 307200
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 228.414 (0.895742)
      standard deviation: 66.9712 (0.262632)
      kurtosis: 4.29925
      skewness: -2.38354
      entropy: 0.417933
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 228.414 (0.895742)
      standard deviation: 66.9712 (0.262632)
      kurtosis: 4.29925
      skewness: -2.38354
      entropy: 0.417933
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 228.414 (0.895742)
      standard deviation: 66.9712 (0.262632)
      kurtosis: 4.29925
      skewness: -2.38354
      entropy: 0.417933
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 228.414 (0.895742)
      standard deviation: 66.9712 (0.262632)
      kurtosis: 4.29928
      skewness: -2.38355
      entropy: 0.417933
  Colors: 4 <--------
  Histogram: <--------
    12730: (0,0,0) #000000 black
    24146: (85,85,85) #555555 srgb(85,85,85)
    9602: (170,170,170) #AAAAAA srgb(170,170,170)
    260722: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
```

Comment: When I try to use this on Linux I get: `biBitCount = 24` and `Debug: Bmp image is not a 4-color bitmap!` so it does not work in my case. Could the OS make a difference?
`

Comment: What is your IM version? Can you post your input and output image?

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#File_structure .
The problem is that you do not specify a color table. According to the wikipedia-article, those are mandatory if the bit depth is less than 8 bit.

Comment: thanks very much for your reply. you are right, the sample BMP is indexed while my result does not mention 'indexed' in the properties. I guess I need to focus on converting the original to indexed image somehow.

Comment: ok, it seems quicker if I wrote my own script to create the BMP image format that I need using raw bytes. thanks for the file structure diagram!

Answer (score 0):

Well done on solving the problem. You could consider also making a personal delegate, or custom delegate, for ImageMagick to help automate the process. ImageMagick is able to delegate formats it cannot process itself to delegates, or helpers, such as your 2-bit helper ;-)

Rather than interfere with the system-wide delegates, which probably live in `/etc/ImageMagick/delegates.xml`, you can make your own in `$HOME/.magick/delegates.xml`. Yours would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<delegatemap>
  <delegate encode="epaper" command="convert &quot;%f&quot; +matte -colors 4 -depth 8 -colorspace gray pgm:- | /usr/local/bin/4_level_gray_4bpp_BMP_converter.py > out.bmp"/>
</delegatemap>
```

Then if you run:

```
identify -list delegate
```

you will see yours listed as a *"known"* helper.

This all means that you will be able to run commands like:

```
convert a.png epaper:
```

and it will do the 2-bit BMP thing automagically.

Comment: Cool! This brings it to the next level! I'd love to give it a go :-)

Comment: I'm going to put all the code here https://github.com/yy502/ePaperDisplay and tidy them up gradually.

Comment: Cool. Click `share` underneath your answer here on StackOverflow and it will give you a URL you can copy and paste into your GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this:

```
convert in.jpg -colorspace gray +matte -colors 2 -depth 1 -resize '640x384>' pgm:- > out.bmp**
```

Answer (score 0):

I too have this epaper display.  After alot of trial and error, I was able to correctly convert the images using ImageMagick using the following command:

```
convert -verbose INPUT.BMP -resize 300x300 -monochrome -colorspace sRGB -colors 2 -depth 1 BMP3:OUTPUT.BMP
```