MissingDelegateError no decode delegate for this image format `EMF' converting image/x-emf to image/x-png
below python function convert emf format image to png.
from wand.image import Image

def process_image(self, image):
    if image.content_type == "image/x-emf":
        with image.open() as image_bytes:
            with Image(blob=image_bytes.read(), format="emf") as img:
                img = img.convert("png")
                encoded_src = base64.b64encode(
                    img.make_blob()).decode("ascii")
        return {"src": "data:{0};base64,{1}".format("PNG", encoded_src)}

it use wand library as you can see. wand itself use ImageMagic internally.
this code works perfectly fine in Windows but in Linux raise below exception:
MissingDelegateError at /doc/s/19/1/0/010212/
no decode delegate for this image format `EMF' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/363

in below this stackoverflow link it says EMF is Windows supported and not supported by Linux.
I got to fix it on Linux, is there any solution for it? its hard to believe that ImageMagic and Wand doesn't support Linux btw.
also wand and magic versions:
# pip freeze | grep -i wand
Wand==0.6.11


# apt list --installed | grep -i magic

imagemagick-6-common/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1 all [installed,automatic]
libmagic-mgc/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 1:5.39-3+deb11u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagic1/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 1:5.39-3+deb11u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6-arch-config/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6-headers/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1 all [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6.q16-6/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6.q16-dev/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickwand-6-headers/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1 all [installed,automatic]
libmagickwand-6.q16-6/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickwand-6.q16-dev/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickwand-dev/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1 all [installed]


I think you'll need to install either Inkscape or LibreOffice. Then work out how to convert EMF files to SVG or other format at the commandline. Then use that knowledge to make your own ImageMagick "delegate". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35841561/2836621

There is an EMF to SVG converter you may be able to use and then add an ImageMagick "delegate" which calls that as above https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/mantic/man1/emf2svg-conv.1.html

Install Inkscape

I got RHEL and installing Inkscape didn't solve my problem. may be I should have write delegates for it

Sorry, I don't use RHEL and there is no docker image for it and you didn't state your RHEL or IM version  nor how you tried to install it, so I can't help.
